# Resize google table chart row height

Tags: javascript, html, css, charts, google-visualization

I have a google visualization dashboard with a table chart (as in https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table) displaying some data shown below. Ive managed to change the font size of the table using **CSS** Class Names but the row height is still the default size - which Id like to change and make smaller.

What Ive used for the font - **CSS**:

```
    .small-font {
    font-size: 10px;
    }
```

javascript:

```
    var cssClassNames = {
    tableCell: 'small-font'
    };
```

Is there a way to do this using **CSS** or another method?

[image: Table Chart Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add `height` to the css class `small-font`...

```
.small-font {
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

be sure to include this chart option...

```
allowHtml: true
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages:['table']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Value'],
    ['2010', 10],
    ['2020', 14],
    ['2030', 16],
    ['2040', 22],
    ['2050', 28]
  ]);

  var options = {
    allowHtml: true,
    cssClassNames: {
      tableCell: 'small-font'
    }
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```css
.small-font {
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Definitely working solution. Didnt work at first with my original code, not sure why but working after a rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not clear with the above details.
However, please try below:

1. remove height of 'td' or 'tr', if used
2. remove cell-padding, if any
3. use border-collapse: collapse; for table